# Python - Output empty line between group of rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with some data in blocks. The separating information is the timestamp of when the data was received.

How can I put an empty line between each block of data? Ultimately, the idea is that this data will be fed to a live blotter via temporary csv and the data blocks need to be separated for ease of reading/replying.

The data in my frame is without a breakline - but I need to separate it like the below example when output in CSV:

```
Ticker  Coupon  Size        Received
UCGIM   5.375   1,000,000   03/07/2018 10:03
INEGRP  2.125   800,000     03/07/2018 10:03
LINGR   1.75    650,000     03/07/2018 10:03
BYLAN   0.75    500,000     03/07/2018 10:03
CMZB    0.875   500,000     03/07/2018 10:03
CXGD    5.75    500,000     03/07/2018 10:03
AAFFP   0       500,000     03/07/2018 10:03

UPCB    3.875   5,000,000   03/07/2018 10:01
UPCB    3.625   5,000,000   03/07/2018 10:01

BMW      0.5    1,000,000   03/07/2018 10:02
ACAFP   1.375   6,100,000   03/07/2018 10:02
ACACB   1.375   2,000,000   03/07/2018 10:02
BPLN    4.154   1,000,000   03/07/2018 10:02
TOTAL   1.875   2,000,000   03/07/2018 10:02
ISPIM   3.928   1,700,000   03/07/2018 10:02
BMW     0.875   1,350,000   03/07/2018 10:02
HTZ     5.5     1,150,000   03/07/2018 10:02
BAMIIM  1.75    1,100,000   03/07/2018 10:02
ENELIM  1.966   1,100,000   03/07/2018 10:02
SRGIM   1.5     1,000,000   03/07/2018 10:02
NDASS   3.5     1,000,000   03/07/2018 10:02

ESM     1.85    8,900,000   03/07/2018 09:46
ISPIM   1.125   5,200,000   03/07/2018 09:46
CARPP   1       4,100,000   03/07/2018 09:46
```

Thanks

Comment: please post the code you have tried and some sample input

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear to me but I think you want to insert rows based on the index of the timestamp?

[Pandas docs Dataframe.append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)